# Iteration on DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Hi guys,
I have a dataframe with 3 columns : 0,1,2.

for the row with "None" values of the column 2 , i want to copy this "None" values on the column 0. Only for the row with None Values. I want the other row of the column 0 to remain the same.

so the columns 0 should be that way :

```
par besoin
None
None
None
par ligne
...
teint
```

Thank you so much

Comment: you should consider using function `apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a dataframe named `df`:

`df.loc[df[2].isnull(), 0] = None`

Where `df.loc[df[2].isnull()` finds rows where the value in column `2` equals `None`, and the remainder, `, 0] = None` sets the value in the column `0` for those rows to `None`.